# Replacing a RegEx with a string of characters with the same length

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace XML tags, with a sequence of repeated characters that has the same number of characters of the tag.

For example:

```
<o:LastSaved>2013-01-21T21:15:00Z</o:LastSaved>
```

I want to replace it with:

```
#############2013-01-21T21:15:00Z##############
```

How can we use RegEx for this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) accepts a function as replacement:

> ```
> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
> ```
>
> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

Here's an example:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: def repl(m):
   ...:     return '#' * len(m.group())
   ...: 

In [3]: re.sub(r'<[^<>]*?>', repl,
   ...:     '<o:LastSaved>2013-01-21T21:15:00Z</o:LastSaved>')
Out[3]: '#############2013-01-21T21:15:00Z##############'
```

The pattern I used may need some polishing, I'm not sure what's the canonical solution to matching XML tags is. But you get the idea.

Comment: the canonical solution to matching XML tags is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/786559) :)

Comment: quick question what does .group() do in the above?

Comment: @HaoS the method basically returns the matched string. Had there been any "groups" in the regex, this method would return them. See the reference here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group