# Variable-length replacement with `re.sub()`

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace all occurrences of 3 or more "=" with an equal-number of "-".

```
def f(a, b):
    '''
    Example
    =======
    >>> from x import y
    '''
    return a == b
```

becomes

```
def f(a, b):
    '''
    Example
    -------
    >>> from x import y
    '''
    return a == b        # don't touch
```

My working but hacky solution is to pass a lambda to `repl` from `re.sub()` that grabs the length of each match:

```
>>> import re

>>> s = """
... def f(a, b):
...     '''
...     Example
...     =======
...     >>> from x import y
...     '''
...     return a == b"""

>>> eq = r'(={3,})'
>>> print(re.sub(eq, lambda x: '-' * (x.end() - x.start()), s))

def f(a, b):
    '''
    Example
    -------
    >>> from x import y
    '''
    return a == b
```

Can I do this without needing to pass a function to `re.sub()`?

My thinking would be that I'd need `r'(=){3,}'` (a variable-length capturing group), but `re.sub(r'(=){3,}', '-', s)` has a problem with greediness, I believe.

Can I modify the regex `eq` above so that the lambda isn't needed?

Comment: I highly doubt so. Why is the lambda not sufficient?

Comment: Possible, but not advisable. The lambda is by far the easiest and most readable solution.

Comment: And for completeness if you use the regex module, that @CasimiretHippolyte mentions there could be [one more jugglery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/5527985) but probably in most cases slower: [`(?<!=)={1,2}(?!=)(*SKIP)(*F)|=`](https://regex101.com/r/9myeWV/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.sub`, this uses some deceptive lookahead trickery and works assuming your pattern-to-replace is always followed by a newline `'\n'`.

```
print(re.sub('=(?=={2}|=?\n)', '-',  s))
def f(a, b):
    '''
    Example
    -------
    >>> from x import y
    '''
    return a == b
```

**Details**
"*Replace an equal sign if it is succeeded by two equal signs or an optional equal sign and newline.*"

```
=        # equal sign if
(?=={2}  # lookahead
|        # regex OR
=?       # optional equal sign
\n       # newline
)
```

Comment: Seems foolproof to me. But how does a fool judge foolproofness?

Comment: @BradSolomon I'd imagine this regex is limited in the sense that it would only replace titular underlines (keep that in mind, as the other solutions may generalise better). Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

With some help from lookahead/lookbehind it is possible to replace by char:

```
>>> re.sub("(=(?===)|(?<===)=|(?<==)=(?==))", "-", "=== == ======= asdlkfj")
... '--- == ------- asdlkfj'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but not advisable.

The way `re.sub` works is that it finds a *complete* match and then it replaces it. It doesn't replace each capture group separately, so things like `re.sub(r'(=){3,}', '-', s)` won't work - that'll replace the entire match with a dash, not each occurence of the `=` character.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(=){3,}', '-', '=== ===')
'- -'
```

So if you want to avoid a lambda, you have to write a regex that matches individual `=` characters - but only if there's at least 3 of them. This is, of course, much more difficult than simply matching 3 or more `=` characters with the simple pattern `={3,}`. It requires some use of lookarounds and looks like this:

```
(?<===)=|(?<==)=(?==)|=(?===)
```

This does what you want:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<===)=|(?<==)=(?==)|=(?===)', '-', '= == === ======')
'= == --- ------'
```

But it's clearly much less readable than the original `lambda` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you can write:

```
regex.sub(r'\G(?!\A)=|=(?===)', '-', s)
```

- `\G` is the position immediately after the last successful match or the start of the string.
- `(?!\A)` forces the start of the string to fail.

The second branch `=(?===)` succeeds when a `=` is followed by two other `=`. Then the next matches use the first branch `\G(?!\A)=` until there are no more consecutive `=`.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/RgfhTD/1)

Answer (score 2):

The question explicitly asks for a solution that doesn't use a function, but for completeness and for someone who is looking for a clearer solution (that doesn't involve lots of regex tricks), it's possible to use a function as in [Replacing a RegEx with a string of characters with the same length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447818/replacing-a-regex-with-a-string-of-characters-with-the-same-length):

`re.sub('={3,}', lambda x: '-' * len(x.group()), s)`